# How do I find the diff between two bags of pairs (A,B) where neither A nor B are unique?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, avro

Suppose I have a bag NEW that contains many pairs (A, B):

```
Pair 1: { "A" : { "long" : someInteger1 }, "B" : { "int" : someInteger2 } }

Pair 2: { "A" : { "long" : someInteger3 }, "B" : { "int" : someInteger4 } }

......
```

I have another bag OLD, which is almost identical to the first bag (it may have a few missing, different, or extra pairs), and I want to compare OLD and NEW by counting how many pairs are the same in both bags. **There may be multiple pairs (A, B) within a bag that have the same A or the same B.**

Things I have already tried using Pig:

1. Joining OLD and NEW on a hash code generated from A and B and
   counting how many have both A and B matching. The count is only about
   half what I expect.
2. Joining OLD and NEW on (A, B) and counting how many results there
   are. The count is only about half what I expect (same as 1 above).
3. Joining OLD and NEW on A and counting how have B matching. For some
   reason, the joined result seems to have weird duplicates:

   Result 1: { "A_new" : { "long" : someInteger1 }, "B_new" : { "int" : someInteger2 }, "A_old" : { "long" : someInteger1 }, "B_old" : { "int" : someInteger2 } }

   Result 2: { "A_new" : { "long" : someInteger1 }, "B_new" : { "int" : someInteger2 }, "A_old" : { "long" : someInteger1 }, "B_old" : { "int" : someInteger3 } }

   Result 3: { "A_new" : { "long" : someInteger1 }, "B_new" : { "int" : someInteger2 }, "A_old" : { "long" : someInteger1 }, "B_old" : { "int" : someInteger4 } }

   Result 4: { "A_new" : { "long" : someInteger1 }, "B_new" : { "int" : someInteger2 }, "A_old" : { "long" : someInteger1 }, "B_old" : { "int" : someInteger5 } }

Answer (score 1):

[DataFu](https://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/guide/set-operations.html) has a awesome library of `Pig` UDFs that you could use.  I think `SetDifference()` is what you are looking for.